# getData failed: Found non-callable @@iterator angular ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, interceptor

ok, I have implement this project before without using Interceptor and it works very well, but I had a problem so I use Interceptor
this error came out after using Interceptor (getData failed: Found non-callable @@iterator)

```
TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
    at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:240)
    at http.js:207
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:207)
    at HttpHeaders.has (http.js:121)
    at TokenInterceptor.intercept (token.interceptor.ts:32)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1895)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1258)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.handle
```

not sure what I did wrong, every solution says you had to ( convert all header values to string) how can I do that??

here is my code :

in service file :

```
get(endpoint: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.env.API_URL +endpoint)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this.log(data)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getData', []))
      );
  }
```

.ts file :

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.httpService.get('auth/createpersonalinfo').subscribe(
      personal_info => {
        this.personal_info = personal_info;
        if(!this.personal_info){
          this.personal_info = {
            first_name: '',
            second_name:'',
            third_name: '',
            family_name: '',
            gender: '',
            national_id: '',
            place_national: '',
            place_birth: '',
            date_birth: '',
            date_national: '',
            date_ex_national: '',
            job: '',
          };
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    );
  }
```

Interceptor file :

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.authService.token;
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': token 
            }
            // headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': token})
            });
        }
        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
            });
        }
        request = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
        });
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('event--->>>', event);
            }
            return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                if (error.error.success === false) {
                this.alertService.presentToast('خطأ في تسجيل الدخول');
                } else {
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
                }
            }
            return throwError(error);
            }));
    }
    showLoader() {
        this.loaderToShow = this.loadingController.create({
          message: 'Processing Server Request'
        }).then((res) => {
          res.present();
    
          res.onDidDismiss().then((dis) => {
            console.log('Loading dismissed!');
          });
        });
        this.hideLoader();
      }
      hideLoader() {
          this.loadingController.dismiss();
      }
}
```

Comment: This line `request = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
        });` makes me think the the error is there, since you are setting headers as the return value of the key-value set. What is the return value of `request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')`?

Answer (score 0):

In your Interceptor file try to change:

```
const token = this.authService.token;
```

to

```
const token = String(this.authService.token);
```